# Changing browser title not blinking browser in taskbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

There are a lot of tutorials on how to do this, and the crux of it seems to be changing the title constantly so the browser tab or taskbar will flash, however this doesn't seem to work for me.

I can see the tab changing its title, but it doesn't flash, so I am wondering if this is something which is no longer allowed by browsers?

I am using Windows 8.1, however have also tried Windows XP

I am using Firefox 25.0.1 and Chrome 31.0.1650.57 and neither of them react how I would expect.

As an example go to:
https://rawgithub.com/heyman/jquery-titlealert/master/example/index.html
(Make sure you click the shield icon in your url bar to allow the scripts to run on that page)

Then if you click the default example button and switch tabs, I would expect the tab hosting that page to blink or flash to indicate the tab has new content, however it doesn't do that for me, although I can see the text changing constantly.

Does anyone else have this issue and know how to solve it or why it occurs? I am looking to implement a feature in a chat system where it notifies you to new messages, however for some reason the code works fine and the title changes, but the taskbar or tab do not flash or anything and the users are really wanting this feature soon.

There seems to be no information on the internet related to this so im a bit confused and came here as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, tab flashes when title is changed ONLY if it is a pinned tab.

Comment: I have just tested in a pinned tab and it doesn't flash there either, if I mouse over I can see the title has changed (as it will just show the favicon otherwise) but no flashing.

Comment: For this purpose, I wrote a piece of code now. You can find it on `http://jsbin.com/aSitIDu/1/edit`. After clicking on button, it waits for 3 seconds and changes the title. I made the tab pinned, pressed the button, and passed to another tab. After 3 seconds, it made the tab shiny blue to indicate the change. If you copy the code into an HTML file and test it, it should work.

Comment: Title changes, no notification happened. If I mouse over I can see the title has changed but there is no flashing notification. I minimized to the taskbar and still no notification. This was in Windows 8 with the mentioned firefox version before, pinned and unpinned, both same result.